# How to only find an exact match of part of a string in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables named "main_cat" and "sub_cat"

The sub categories can belong to more than one main category, stored in a VARCHAR called "cat_id" simply separated by commas "1, 8, 17" etc.

How can I select a sub category based on a main category it belongs to?

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM sub_cat WHERE cat_id LIKE '%{$catId}%'
```

But with a $catId of "1" that would also return "10, 21, 14" etc.

Any other variations of LIKE I try do not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*FIND_IN_SET*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set),but if possible that you can change your schema then normalize it do not store comma separated ids.

```
SELECT * FROM sub_cat 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('{$catId}',cat_id )
```

A suggestion for schema 1 table for categories(id,name) 1 for sub categories(id,name) and a junction table(id,category_id,sub_category_id) that relates the sub category to its multiple parents parent.Then you  can use a joined query like

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM sub_categories s
JOIN junction_table j ON(s.id =j.sub_category_id)
WHERE j.category_id ='{$catId}'
```

Comment: How would you recommend storing references to multiple categories?

Comment: Thanks, FIND_IN_SET is what I was looking for short term but I'll give the other option a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exact match, don't use wild cards :) YOu may have to pre process the list using explode() to put it into an array first though.